# date_time difference output is not correct

Tags: java

I have written this java code to get the difference between system_date_time and my_date_time, when I run this code system_date_time was 2015-02-19 06:01:00, so the difference should be 24 hours = 86400 seconds, but this code is giving -2592002 as output.
So please help to fix the problem.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class A {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws ParseException {

        String dateString = "2015-02-20 06:01:00"; // end_date_time
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date myDate = sdf.parse(dateString);

        System.out.println( (myDate.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000 );

    }

}
```

Comment: your dateformat is wrong u have to mention yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. You will get +2 Reputation also! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Note the MM (MM is Month, mm is minute)

You parsed the Date wrong (so it gave you sometimes in January)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `java.sql.Timestamp` for what you trying to achieve.

```
String dateString = "2015-02-20 06:01:00"; // end_date_time
Timestamp myTimeStamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateString);
System.out.println( ((myTimeStamp.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your date format to

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

`MM` is for months `mm` is for minutes

Comment: The answer was was not refreshed and appeared only after i posted my answer. And that is a very lame reason to give down-vote. There can be two similar answers and appear commonly on many questions throughout SO.

Answer (score 0):

Update code here, first change is use MM instead of mm in SimpleDateFormat and another change in sysout

```
    String dateString = "2015-02-18 15:39:00"; // end_date_time
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date myDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println( (  System.currentTimeMillis()- myDate.getTime()) / 1000 );
```